# S3 website hosting - Too Many Redirects

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

I have a React app served from an S3 bucket which is set up for static website hosting, behind a Cloudfront distribution, with a custom domain (https://dev.meal-plannr.com) managed by Route 53.

When I go to my custom domain or the Cloudfront URL I get a "Too many redirections" (Safari) or "dev.meal-plannr.com redirected you too many times." (Chrome). Going to the S3 bucket URL loads the website fine. Interestingly I only get the error in Chrome if I have the dev tools displayed - without that the website loads correctly on all URLs.

Here is the configuration for each of the services mentioned above.

**S3**

[image: S3 static website hosting configuration]

**Cloudfront**

Origin configuration:

[image: Cloudfront origin configuration]

General:

[image: Cloudfront general configuration]

Behaviours:

[image: Cloudfront behaviours configuration]

Error Pages:

[image: Cloudfront error pages configuration]

**Route 53**

[image: Route 53 configuration]

Up until around 30 minutes ago my S3 bucket was set up to redirect to https://dev.meal-plannr.com but I've since removed this. Have I misconfigured something?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue after setting up a redirect for my S3 bucket. After clearing my Cloudfront Cache, everything was back to normal.